# How to avoid printing unnecessary UWSGI error messages in the log file

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

My Flask app is generating thousands of

> 'OSError: write error'

messages in my log file (my log file is defined in the .ini file; logger = '/temp/my_app.log). Most of them happen due to users disconnecting from the server or cancelling a request. I only need my error handling messages to show up in the log file, and not these uwsgi error messages. Is there any configuration that I need to do in my uwsgi .ini file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several configuration options that may be helpful in your case:

- [ignore-sigpipe](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#ignore-sigpipe)
- [ignore-write-errors](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#ignore-write-errors)
- [disable-write-exception](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#disable-write-exception)

Personally I prefer to set all three options.